# Is this a correct integral for calculating current of the given Green's function?

Tags: electric-current, greens-functions

I am trying to calculate numerically a current from the given Green's function.  I am aware that to calculate density of states of a Green's function I must do the integral as follows:

$ \tag1\ DOS(E) =\frac{ -1 }{2*\pi^2}*Im*\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}G(E,k)*dk $

and,

$ \tag2\ G(E) =\frac{ 1 }{E-i*n-2*cos(k)} $

[image]

is a Green's advanced function.  Equation (1) and (2) shows how to calculated DOS using the integral.  To calculate current for simple two contacts model of quantum transport I assume the following equation:

$ \tag3\ I(V) =\frac{ 2*e }{h}*Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}T(E)*(F(E-V)-F(E))*dE $

and T(E) is the transmitance function expressed in terms of Gamma's and Retarded/Advanced Green's function.   My question is that in order to calculate current numerically  do I have to do one integral over dE and keeping k constant at some value or do I have to do double integral (first one over dk and second integral over dE)?  Both give me same results in curve plot (I-V line going through (0,0) but amplitudes are different)

[image]

$ \tag4\ I(V) =\frac{ 2*e }{h}*Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}T(E)*(F(E-V)-F(E))*dE,  and:   k-constant$

[image]

$ \tag5\ I(V) =\frac{ 2*e }{h}*Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}*(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}T(E)*(F(E-V)-F(E))*dk)*dE$

[image]

Comment: I'm not used to see such codings on this website, perhaps could you present your question with the physical concepts instead of a code?

Comment: @gingras.ol, Thanks for reply.  I removed the code and added physical concepts as you suggested.